# Does `reboot` go through GRUB?

Tags: grub2, reboot

I had a pretty broken GRUB set up where booting required the enter key to be pressed. However today I ran `sudo reboot` and it powered off and came back up without a hitch. I doubt I fixed my GRUB issue (unless apt-get upgrade/update would affect it) so I thought that maybe the reboot doesn't go down as far as GRUB?

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` can regenerate grub configs, depending on which packages are upgraded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reboot` does a proper reboot, it won't bypass GRUB.

`apt-get update` would not affect it, but `apt-get upgrade` may have upgraded GRUB or installed a new kernel, and as a result regenerated GRUB's configuration.